# Table of column counts for a data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, apply, tabular

I have a data frame with columns of categorical data supplied as strings.  The categories for each column are the same, e.g.:

```
myDF=data.frame(col1=sample(c("a","b","c"),10,replace=T),
                col2=sample(c("a","b","c"),10,replace=T),
                col3=sample(c("a","b","c"),10,replace=T))
```

I would like to generate a table of counts in each category by column.

When all columns have all categories included, this can be done with `apply` using the function `table`, for instance:

```
> myDF
   col1 col2 col3
1     a    c    a
2     b    b    b
3     a    a    b
4     b    b    a
5     c    c    a
6     a    a    a
7     a    c    c
8     a    a    c
9     c    a    a
10    a    a    b
> apply(myDF,2,table)
  col1 col2 col3
a    6    5    5
b    2    2    3
c    2    3    2
```

However, if one column is missing some categories, this doesn't work because `table` doesn't know what categories to expect:

```
myDF=data.frame(col1=sample(c("a","b","c"),10,replace=T),
                col2=sample(c("a","b","c"),10,replace=T),
                col3=sample(c("a","b"),10,replace=T))
```

Gives:

```
> myDF
   col1 col2 col3
1     c    a    a
2     a    a    b
3     b    a    a
4     c    c    a
5     c    a    a
6     c    c    a
7     c    b    a
8     c    b    b
9     a    a    a
10    b    b    a
> apply(myDF,2,table)    
$col1

a b c 
2 2 6 

$col2

a b c 
5 3 2 

$col3

a b 
8 2
```

How can I produce a table that looks like the first one, with 0 for any missing categories?

Comment: See, also, something like `table(stack(lapply(myDF, as.character)))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could collect all the factor levels and use those in `apply`:

```
#get the levels from the whole data.frame
all_levels <- levels(unlist(myDF))

#convert each column to factor using the levels from above
#and then use table (which will return a zero for any missing levels)
apply(myDF, 2, function(x) table(factor(x, levels = all_levels)))
```

Output:

```
  col1 col2 col3
a    1    4    7
b    5    2    3
c    4    4    0

> myDF
   col1 col2 col3
1     b    a    a
2     c    b    a
3     c    c    b
4     b    a    b
5     b    c    a
6     c    c    a
7     c    b    a
8     b    a    b
9     a    c    a
10    b    a    a
```

Comment: Works great on the example.  For the real data, the columns were not yet coerced into factors, but I was able to successfully use the same approach with `unique` in place of `levels`.

Comment: Sounds great! Happy to help :)

Answer (score 1):

We can use `mtabulate`

```
library(qdapTools)
t(mtabulate(myDF))
#    col1 col2 col3
#a    2    5    8
#b    2    3    2
#c    6    2    0
```

It works for both the cases mentioned in the OP's post